# How to loop a FIFO reader program in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a c program in ubuntu that writes and reads in fifo pipe. I already have the program writing working perfectly, I now have a problem reading in a loop.

My reading program :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_CTRLS 80

void main()
{
printf("test1");
   char ch2[MAX_CTRLS];
   int pipe1;
   pipe1 = open("/tmp/ctrl", O_RDONLY);
printf("test2");
   read(pipe1, ch2, MAX_CTRLS);
   printf("%s",ch2);
  close(pipe1);
}
```

This program is supposed to read in the fifo, store it in ch2 then print in ch2. But when running it normally it works perfectly, while running it in a loop, it doesn't do anything.

Here is writing program 1 :

```
void send(char ch2[MAX_CTRLS])
{
    int create;
    create = mkfifo("/tmp/ctrl", 0666);
    int pipe1;
    pipe1 = open("/tmp/ctrl", O_WRONLY);
    write(pipe1, ch2, MAX_CTRLS);
    close(pipe1);
}
```

This one works using another program I have, that has a line like this :

```
ch2[0] = 'a';
printf("%s",ch2);
send(ch2);
```

The printf helps me confirm that ch2 is set properly. I need the reading program to loop the reading function, aka print everytime what is set in ch2.

I just ant it to print a in this case, everytime my program launches send(ch2).

Thaks in advance

Comment: What does "running it in a loop" mean? I don't see any loop.

Comment: We need more infos. But it seems, the read will get blocked in a loop, if there is nothing to read. `select()` would be your friend.

Comment: I want to add a while(1) to run the reading program on a loop.

Comment: You probably want to use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or the old [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) in some kind of [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)

Answer (score 0):

I figure you want to have a loop that open the pipe and reads if anything is there, with no delay, then goes to sleep for a while before next reading.
Suggest something like this, u might also swap for(;;) to While(boolValue == true)

```
int fd = -1, naptime = 200; // 200msec
```

`for (;;){
    fd = open(pipe, mode|nodelay);
    if (fd != -1){
      int st = read (fd, buf, sizeof(buf));  /* open OK */
      // do your printing of data if any exist - st holds read chars 
      if(st >0) printf(buf);
    }
    sleep(naptime); // sleep til next reading
  }`

Comment: `sleep(naptime = 200)` sleeps for 200 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the reading program to loop the reading function, aka print everytime what is set in ch2.

Simply adding *a while(1) to run the reading program on a loop* won't do good, because `read()` from a FIFO that has been closed (which is the case after the first run of the *writing program*) doesn't block, but rather returns 0, and we surely don't want a busy waiting `read()` loop. So, we need a means of waiting for something readable from the FIFO. If we have the fortune to run Linux, we can use [`inotify`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to get notified of writings to the FIFO. The reading code could be:

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>

    int fd = inotify_init();
    inotify_add_watch(fd, "/tmp/ctrl", IN_MODIFY);
    pipe1 = open("/tmp/ctrl", O_RDONLY);
    struct inotify_event inev;
    while (read(fd, &inev, sizeof inev))
        if (read(pipe1, ch2, MAX_CTRLS) > 0)
            printf("%s", ch2), fflush(stdout);
```